# How to reset Fluent UI choice group selection

Tags: fluentui-react

I am using a choice group in y page and I have a situation where I need to clear radio button selection (if any). I am using selectedKey property n IChoiceGroup. On load, when I pass correct key id, it does select the right radio button, however, when I pass "undefined" to the selectedKey property, hoping to uncheck all selection, it doesnt do anything. The choice control still shows the previous selection.

Comment: Hi, provide Codepen working example or code inside question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting "selectedKey" to null?

```
<ChoiceGroup selectedKey={null} options={options} onChange={_onChange} />
```

As in this codepen: https://codepen.io/pkatny/pen/JjypJaX

Works for me...

Answer (score 0):

`selectedKey={undefined}`

As the type supports

```
IChoiceGroupProps.selectedKey?: string | number | undefined
```